# Is there performance cost when more nodes are added to Redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

In [Redis Cluster official specification](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec), it says it supports "linear scalability up to 1000 nodes". Does it mean that there is no performance cost when adding more nodes to a cluster as long as the total number of nodes is below 1000?